# Implications of manual server time change

Tags: 14.04, server, ssh, time

I am running a web server on ubuntu 14.04 (nginx as a proxy for a node application, as well as a go application daemonized using supervisor). I would like to know the implications of manually changing the date/time of the server.

I haven't been able to obtain any information that leads me to think this has potentially serious implications.

Unfortunately I can't use something like [libfaketime](https://github.com/wolfcw/libfaketime) because it doesn't interface with my applications running on the server, and I'll need all applications that rely on time to be synchronized.

Will changing the time manually affect services like SSH, or anything else I may be unaware of?

Comment: Log file incongruity is the big issue, but otherwise things like nginx shouldn't be affected; HOWEVER make sure that your applications are not going to be time-sensitive - 2FA-enabled applications things are sometimes time-sensitive and won't like time changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. SSH does not care about time.

Only service I know which cares about time is kerberos (also if you are using kerberos authentication in SSH, or some kind of IDM - IPA, or so). But somebody might point out some more troublesome.

Another drawback would be in log files. I know that rsyslog had some problems when playing with time, but it is probably not serious.